# how to protect asp.net mvc 3 site from url queries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, url

My problem is that when people type in url something like home/DeleteSong?id=139 they are getting to my actions in the home controller, and can delete songs and stuff. I believe I can use [authorize] attribute but wouldnt logged in users still be able to type in url to use my actions which I don't want to happen. I mostly use ajax requests to communicate with the server so should I check my actions for an ajax request and if it is let it do it's thing otherwise do something else. I would like to set up my project in a way that when a user types in any url I would just redirect to home page.. how do I do it, and would this solve my problem?

my action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteTopTenFav(int id)
    {
        var song = repository.GetTopTenFav(id);

        var points = repository.FindPoints(song.UserName);
        foreach (var item in points)
        {
            item.TopTenFav = null;
        }

        repository.DeleteTopTenFav(song);
        repository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my jquery ajax delete function:

```
   $("#topTenContainer").on("click", ".btnDeleteTopTenFavSong", function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteTopTenFav/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: function () { HideAjaxLoader(), ChangeColorShowMsg("green"), ShowSuccessMsgAndReplaceTopTenSong("Song deleted successfully", button) },
        error: function () { HideAjaxLoader(), ChangeColorShowMsg("red"), ShowMsg("Song could not be deleted, please try again") }
    });
});
```

Comment: no, that would not solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller should be verifying that the logged-on user has permission to take the requested action on the indicated item, perhaps by checking an "owner" field or some related item.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authhorize]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var image = repo.GetImage(id);
    if(image.UploadedByUser.id == User.Identity.Name)
    {
      // .... do the delete
    }
    else
    {
       //...don't do it
    } 
}
```

Also, you should not be taking actions based on GET requests, as this exposes your users to cross site request forgery attacks. You should use POST for all "destructive" or "creative" actions, always, and consider using an anti forgery token.

Comment: No you don't... not if people can type in a url and cause something to be deleted.

Comment: He probably has an index page with a list of songs, clicking delete link for a row passes id in querystring and redirects user to confirmation page that does the delete via http post.

Comment: yup problably similar, is that a bad design or something?

Comment: @Alan "probably"? You don't know? Your question starts off saying that people can type in a url that will cause files to be deleted. Are you saying your question inaccurately states your problem?

Comment: check my edit, i have added my ajax code, as well as my action

Comment: since you have it specifed as [HttpPost] someone could not do what you said at the beginning of your question, then (just type in a URL). So you would be OK for that part of things. Still need to make sure you check in your action method that what happens is appropriate for the user. Your action method doesn't seem to be doing anything to make sure that the user acting can do what they are.

Answer (score 1):

A normal best practice is to use POST requests when you want to perform actions like deleting stuff. If you think about the nature of the web, it’s kind of strange to issue a GET to have something deleted. Make sure that you do your deletes with post and decorate your methods with the attribute `[HttpPost]`

Comment: I have the httpPost attr but the user passes in the name of the action and the parameter id of the song in the url

Comment: If you have the httpPost it's impossible to access the action by typing the url in the browser.

Comment: @Alan KMan is correct here: if what you state in your question is really happening, you do *not* have the proper methods decorated with HttpPost.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you can also specify roles when using the authorize tag on your controllers and action methods. EG: For admin controllers or actions

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

If that is not applicable in your scenario and it requires custom logic then add the check first thing in your action method. If they do not have permission it should redirect to an error page specifying that to the user.

Comment: Yup; return a status code 403, for example if it's a user ownership thing, and the current user does not own the image id being submitted for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require POSTs and use CSRF protection.

To do that, use the `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgery]` attributes.